# Remove string before double line break using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
this is my text
more text
more text

text I want
is below
```

I just want the text below the double line break and not the stuff before.

Here is what I thought should work:

```
myString.replaceFirst(".+?(\n\n)","");
```

However it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Only the first line gets removed, so only after one /n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the below **regex** for your purpose: -

```
str = str.replaceFirst("(?s).+?(\n\n)", "");
```

Because, you want to match anything including the `newline` character before it encounters two newline characters back to back.

---

Note that `dot(.)` does not matches a `newline`, so it would stop matching on encountering the `first newline character`.

If you want your `dot(.)` to match newline, you can use `Pattern.DOTALL`, which in case of `str.replaceFirst`, is achieved by using `(?s)` expression.

From the documentation of [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL): -

> In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a
>   line terminator. By default this expression does not match line
>   terminators.
>
> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s).

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

`s = s.substring(s.indexOf("\n\n") + 2);`

Note that it might be +1, +2, or +3. I don't feel like like breaking out my computer to test it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split here is an example

```
String newString = string.split("\n\n")[1];
```